# ¿Cómo hacer que no cuente el 0 como el número menor?

Tags: c#

El programa debe mostrar por pantalla la cantidad de números leídos, el mayor, el menor y la media de los números leídos.

```
        int numero = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        int mayor = numero;
        int menor = numero;
        int suma = 0;
        int promedio = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese los valores a evaluar");
        numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (numero > 0)
        {
            if (numero >= mayor)
            {
                mayor = numero;
            }
            else if (numero <= menor)
            {
                menor = numero;
            }
            else { }
            suma = suma + numero;
            numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            contador = contador + 1;

        }
        promedio = suma / contador;
        Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de numeros ingresados = " + contador);
        Console.WriteLine("Mayor = " + mayor);
        Console.WriteLine("Menor = " + menor);
        Console.WriteLine("Media = " + promedio);
    }
}
```

}

En la consola toma el numero 0 que indica cuando detenerse como el numero menor.

Comment: Eso es porque estás inicializando `menor` con 0, y cuando el número ingresado sea 0 nunca se va a ejecutar, por lo que siempre va a ser 0. Te recomiendo que inicialices `menor` con un número muy alto, incluso puedes inicializarlo con `menor = 0xFFFFFFFF` y así seguro que todos los números que ingreses van a ser casi seguro menores que ese valor inicial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El truco del problema es que inicialices las variables min como el máximo número posible y max como el mínimo posible. Así, al ingresar un número ese primer número reemplaza inmediatamente ambos valores

```
static void Main()
    {
        int numero = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        int mayor = int.MinValue;
        int menor = int.MaxValue;
        int suma = 0;
        int promedio = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese los valores a evaluar");
        numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (numero > 0)
        {
            if (numero > mayor)
            {
                mayor = numero;
            }
            if (numero < menor)
            {
                menor = numero;
            }
         
            suma = suma + numero;
            numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            contador = contador + 1;

        }
        if(contador > 0) {
            promedio = suma / contador;
            Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de numeros ingresados = " + contador);
            Console.WriteLine("Mayor = " + mayor);
            Console.WriteLine("Menor = " + menor);
            Console.WriteLine("Media = " + promedio);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no se ingresaron números");
        }
       

    }
```